# Accessing POST parameter with file upload in PHP

Tags: php

Trying to access the POST parameter passed with image uploading. When I print $_POST, the output is as follows:

```
array (
     '%entity' => 'org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity@532d2d84',
)
```

The PHP code is as follows:

```
  $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['source']['tmp_name']);
  $image = imagecreatefromstring( $data );

  $ifp = fopen( '1.png', "wb" ); 
  fwrite( $ifp, $data); 
  fclose( $ifp ); 
  echo '<pre>'; 
  print_r($POST);
```

User id is sent along with the file in POST request.
How to access the USERID which is passed with the file?

Comment: Did you even try ```$_POST['%entity']?```

Comment: Tried it. Prints the value shown above. But actually an ID is being passed.

Comment: What do you mean by "an ID is being passed"? Are you suggesting that along with the '%entity' parameter there should be another one? If is that so, please reformulate your question, you didn't tell us about any ID being passed....

Comment: Multipart post is sent from an android App which uses AQuery library [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI)

Comment: It seems your $_POST superglobal knows nothing about USERID, so are you sure is being sent? Can you check ```php://input``` (raw request) to see if it's there?

Comment: Hey thanks @mTorres. Sorted out. Actually it was not sent in a proper way from app.

Comment: Glad you worked it out :-) @Tejas

Answer (score 0):

In your output you have listed `key => value`. You have to use the `key` part on `$_POST` array.

Just try with:

```
$_POST['%entity']
```